# How to move text to X,Y position within a .PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, model-view-controller, itext

I am generating a pdf using iTextSharp. I would like to align the text "LayerX" onto each of the images. However, I am unsure how to do so. I see that images have a .SetAbsolutePosition method, unsure why text doesn't. This is my code so far.

```
            using(Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30)) 
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
            document.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/Content/layer.jpg"));

            var textAttributes = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 6, BaseColor.BLACK);
            

            int temp = 0;
            image.ScaleAbsolute(36, 12); //scale image
            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
            {
                temp = 698 + (10 * i);
                Chunk coreText = new Chunk("     Layer" + i, textAttributes);

                //don't know what to put here, would like something like the following
                //coreText.SetAbsolutePosition(25, temp); ---> something like this

                document.Add(coreText);

                image.SetAbsolutePosition(25, temp);
                document.Add(image);
                document.Add(new Paragraph());
            }

            document.Close();
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test2");
            Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
            "attachment;filename=Diagram - " + variable.Substring(0,8)                         + ".pdf");
        }
```

I would like to align the text LayerX onto the images such as Layer1. However, the image does the follow. Any help?

[image]

Thank you very much for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to place text with this code.

```
Document document = new Document(pageSize, 25, 25, 30, 30)
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(corePhrase, 65, 0, 35, temp + 14, 0, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
ct.Go();
```

Parameters for .SetSimpleColumn

1. the phrase
2. lower-left-x
3. lower-left-y
4. upper-right-x (llx + width)
5. upper-right-y (lly + height)
6. leading (The amount of blank space between lines of print)
7. alignment.